# What's the more elegant and efficient way to make a request at intervals?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently making some changes to an API and the problem here is that we request data from another server but for the server to process our request and for security we first ask them for an AccessToken, if the token is valid and is still alive (those tokens last for 2 seconds, I didn't know how to put it correctly in english, sorry) then everything is fine, if the token is not OK we can't ask them for anything.

The situation here is that now the API makes the request without asking for a token first, and if the current token (because when the API is started it asks for the token) is not valid then it catches the error and asks for a new token and then makes the request again.

I don't like it. I feel it would be much simpler and clearer if I ask for a new token every two seconds instead of catching an error.

How can I accomplish this but in an elegant and efficient way? The most basic form I can think of right now is by putting a promise in a self executing function every two seconds with a timer. But I don't think that's the best way to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not a good idea to keep requesting a new token every two seconds. It puts unnecessary extra load on the server, especially if most of the tokens will go unused. You should create a variable: `var validToken` and after receiving a valid token, set it to `validToken=true` do a `setTimeout` for two seconds and set it to `validToken=false`. If `validToken==false`, ask for a new token before making the API call.

Comment: Yes, I was going to ask this too but I had to go out for lunch. Is the 2 seconds expiration time really necessary? Like, maybe it should be 1 or 2 minutes, and new tokens should be retrieved only when you have requests pending to be sent.

Comment: The expiration time is set by the guys who made the API, it's not up to me.

Comment: Oh, alright. Then that's something out of your control.
Anyway, there are now two answers you can look at.

Comment: Just marked your answer as the right one. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: @RenéVidrialesTrujillo how do you know when their token expires? Is it explicitly stated, to the ms - on whose box? Do you know how long your request to their server takes? Do you know how long their token lookup takes on their side? Do you know if it's the real expiration date, or if they give you 50ms of leeway? You will still be dealing with error-cases, where tokens were close to expiring when you sent them, or where the DNS lookup took longer than you thought, or the proxy. You now have a solution in search of a problem. Edge-cases != elegant.

Comment: I know because when the token is expired/invalid they send me that as response haha. I don't know the other data.

Comment: Throwing exceptions in case token expires after the request is sent but before it is received, in order to catch them outside and repeat the request, would still help in order to cover the edge-cases Nordguard mentions, like network delay and/or lack of stability. I'd suggest keeping on mind both of our answers, in order to avoid the traffic overhead generated by either constantly polling for tokens (regardless of if they will be used at all) or sending a request after a long period without them (that you can guess will surely fail), and easily recover from any anomalies that might happen.

Comment: [Off-topic] Also, @RenéVidrialesTrujillo, I see you're from a LatAm country, just like me :D . That's cool.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My two cents here: you could keep track of when your current token was retrieved in, let's say, milliseconds from UTC or nanoseconds from system startup, so you can check if it is still valid based on its expiration time before sending a request. If it has expired already, you would just pull a new one before sending your request, thus saving a request/response cicle. Information about the token (like the time such token has before it expires) could be delivered with the token itself, depending of the transmission protocol or data format. It all could be handled in a single thread (or a single group of them) and you would only get new tokens when you need them, saving bandwidth for both client and server.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: How do you deal with all of the transfer time? You still need to keep every edge-case your code previously had, because you're dealing with a 3rd-party server, so there are DNS lookups, and network routing. What if you sent the request in time, but you are 2ms too late, by the time they get around to actually checking your token? If it's in a Redis cache, and they auto-expire it's not like they can add buffer; it's just gone. There are so many edges here, caused by preempting something you can't control, anyway.

Answer (score -1):

There really isn't anything particularly elegant about polling. Nor about thrashing their system, to ask for tokens, constantly.

A more elegant solution is to incorporate some functional polymorphism, and recursion and/or chaining.

```
const handleInvalidToken = (request, token, data) => err => 
  invalidTokenErr(err)
    ? getNewToken().then(token => request(token, data))
    : Promise.reject(err);

const handleSomeRequest = (token, data) =>
  doAThing(token, data)
    .catch(handleInvalidToken(doAThing, token, data));


handleSomeRequest(userData.token, request.body)
  .then(handleSuccess)
  .catch(handleCatastrophicFailure);
```

You've now taken ALL of the crazy, inelegant code that you had, turned it into simple functions and higher-order functions, which should be clearly understood, and clearly mapped the control flow.